# DC shunt motor rotation

Tags: dc, dc-motor

ln case of dc shunt motor , how can a field winding produce rotational torque,whose field current is very small when compared to armature current. i mean how can it provide  so much attraction ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In case of dc shunt motor , how can a field winding produce rotational
>   torque,whose field current is very small when compared to armature
>   current.

Because a field winding has many times the number of turns compared to a series winding that operates directly with the armature current. The attraction is proportional to ampere turns and not just amps.